# What is the maximum degrees per step of a stepper motor for a 3D printer?

Tags: stepper-motor, 3d-printing

I am making a reprap rostock (delta style printer) and I am trying to use as many parts I already have as possible. The stepper I have are 7.2 degrees per step. Even with microstepping, would this resolution get me high quality prints?

Comment: With microstepping you can achieve pretty much arbitrary resolution limited only by play of the parts and static friction (=force needed to turn) the motor.